# Tailwind and React image isn't getting centered?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am trying to center an image

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import { BsFillMoonStarsFill } from 'react-icons/bs';
import { AiFillTwitterCircle, AiFillLinkedin, AiFillYoutube } from 'react-icons/ai';
import Image from "next/image";
import deved from '../public/dev-ed-wave.png';
import design from '../public/design.png';
import code from '../public/code.png';
import consulting from '../public/consulting.png'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Tom Miller Portofolio</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main className="bg-white px-10">
        <section className="min-h-screen ">
          <nav className="py-10 mb-12 flex justify-between">
            <h1 className="text-xl font-burtons">TomMiller</h1>
            <ul className="flex items-center">
              <li>
                <BsFillMoonStarsFill className="cursos-pointer text-xl" />
              </li>
              <li>
                <a className="bg-gradient-to-r from-cyan-500 to-teal-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded-xl" href="#">Resume</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
          <div className="text-center p-10 py-10">
            <h2 className="text-5xl py-2 text-teal-600 font-medium">Tom Miller</h2>
            <h3 className="text-2xl py-2">Developer</h3>
            <p className="text-md py-5 leading-8 text-gray-800">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci quam tempora a nemo dolorum ipsum unde esse modi consequuntur asperiores commodi ab exercitationem sequi quod, sunt repellat. Repellat, pariatur provident!
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className="text-5xl flex justify-center gap-16 py-3 text-gray-600">
            <AiFillLinkedin />
            <AiFillYoutube />
          </div>
          <div className="relative mx-auto bg-gradient-to-b from-teal-500 rounded-full w-80 h-80 mt-20 overflow-hidden">
            <Image src={deved} layout="fill" objectFit="cover" />

          </div>

        </section>

        <section>
          <div>
            <h3 className="text-3xl py-1">Services I offer</h3>
            <p className="text-md py-2 leading-8 text-gray-800">
              This is just a <span className="text-teal-500">little</span> test but this is a <span className="text-teal-500">website!</span>

            </p>

            <p className="text-md py-2 leading-8 text-gray-800">
              This is just a <span className="text-teal-500">little</span> test but this is a <span className="text-teal-500">website!</span>

            </p>
          </div>


          <div>
            <div className="text-center shadow-lg p-10 rounded-xl my-10">
              <Image src={design} width={100} height={100} alt={''} />
              <h3 className="text-lg font-medium pt-8 pb-2">Bewautfiul Designs</h3>
              <p className="py-2">
                Frrewtwetewtoertrrtotrmyortmyotrmyrto
              </p>
              <h4 className="py-4 text-teal-600">Design Tools I use</h4>
              <p className="text-gray-800 py-1">Photoshop</p>
              <p className="text-gray-800 py-1">C</p>
              <p className="text-gray-800 py-1">C++</p>
            </div>

            <div className="text-center shadow-lg p-10 rounded-xl my-10">
              <Image src={design} width={100} height={100} alt={''} />
              <h3 className="text-lg font-medium pt-8 pb-2">Bewautfiul Designs</h3>
              <p className="py-2">
                Frrewtwetewtoertrrtotrmyortmyotrmyrto
              </p>
              <h4 className="py-4 text-teal-600">Design Tools I use</h4>
              <p className="text-gray-800 py-1">Photoshop</p>
              <p className="text-gray-800 py-1">C</p>
              <p className="text-gray-800 py-1">C++</p>
            </div>

            <div className="text-center shadow-lg p-10 rounded-xl my-10">
              <Image src={design} width={100} height={100} alt={''} />
              <h3 className="text-lg font-medium pt-8 pb-2">Bewautfiul Designs</h3>
              <p className="py-2">
                Frrewtwetewtoertrrtotrmyortmyotrmyrto
              </p>
              <h4 className="py-4 text-teal-600">Design Tools I use</h4>
              <p className="text-gray-800 py-1">Photoshop</p>
              <p className="text-gray-800 py-1">C</p>
              <p className="text-gray-800 py-1">C++</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

but it's not getting centered. The text is getting centered but for some reason the image isn't moving? Can anyone help?

I tried adding flex and justify-content but nothing works I'm just curious in also understanding simply why this doesn't work? I mean the text is getting centered.

Comment: provide code in code sandbox

Comment: Could You Show us Your package.json file ?